# The position of the pixel I want is not the same as what my code outputs

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm writing a code that should output the position of a white pixel (rgb of [255,255,255]). And from the pixels that are white I want the code to give me the pixel that is at the highest point. I need this because I want to measure the height of an object that happens to have a small region at the tip of its height that is white in color, but the (x,y) position that my code gives out is half wrong, the y position is correct but the x position is wrong. I wrote a line that would draw a blue circle at the position of the pixel that the code outputs, the y position is correct but the x axis is wrong. How can I solve this? here is the code[image: here is the image I used]

```
import numpy as np 
import tkinter
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from vpython import *
from numpy import loadtxt
import math
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = cv2.imread("Masked_image.jpg")
# Find white pixels
white = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
white_pixels = np.all(img == white, axis=-1)
white_columns = white_pixels.max(axis=0)
white_rows = white_pixels.max(axis=1)
white_rows_indexes = np.where(white_rows == True)[0]
white_column_indexes = np.where(white_columns == True)[0]
ypoints = np.array(white_column_indexes)
xpoints = np.array(white_rows_indexes)
YY=list(ypoints)
test_list=list(zip(ypoints,xpoints))
print(test_list)
subcoords = [(x, y) for x, y in test_list if x==min(YY)]
print(subcoords)
cv2.circle(img, subcoords[0], 1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
im = Image.open(r"Masked_image.jpg")
img1 = mpimg.imread("Masked_image.jpg")
imgplot1 = plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `xpoints = np.array(indices[0])` -- numpy array indexing is by default row-major, so those are not "X points", they are "Y points" (and vice versa).

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve] -- right now there are things missing (`YY` is undefined), and on the other hand some dead code, useless imports and commented out code of no use. | NB: JPEG is a terrible choice of file format, when you want to look for pixels of very specific colour. Many pixels which look pure white aren't, and it is rather hard to tell whether this is the intent or just JPEG artifacts.

Comment: @DanMašek I have made some changes to my code. The y position is correct this time but the x position is wrong. I understand what you said about indexing being row-major by default but I don't know how to tackle this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if this is the code, and you're judging it by what's shown by matplotlib, then it's rather simple that you can't see any changes -- in last three lines, you reload the original unmodified image from the disk and then display it. All the prior processing is quite irrelevant then.

Comment: Beside consistent confusion regarding row/columns vs X/Y, the root of the problems lies in the `zip(ypoints,xpoints)`. At that point, there's no correlation between the two arrays (they don't necessarily even have the same length), so you're just making up random points.

Comment: Really most of that work is overly complicated. You can pretty much reduce it to: Find white pixels, turn into list of (X,Y), sort that by (Y,X), show the first coordinate pair in the list. https://pastebin.com/GajfNVfR